# Find cycle which contains two vertices in undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I need to find shortest non-recursive cycle from first vertex to second vertex in undirected graph.

Example.

vertices: { A, B, C, D, E }

edges: { A, C }, { B, C }, { A, B }, { C, D }, { D, E }

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNmS4.png)

I need to find cycle from A to C. The answer here is { A, B, C }

I've already tried to implement BSP algorithm and it works, but BSP is too slow.

Need your help!

Answer (score -1):

Just run a Breadth-first-search (BFS) from the second node and stop when you reach the first one.

BFS is O(M) (M is the number of edges reachable from the start node). You can't do it more efficient.

If your implementation is too slow you might be using some inefficient datastructures or language (don't use interpreters). If you post the code somebody might be able to help you speed it up.

Comment: Sorry for my inattention, i've implemented DFS, not BSP. Here is my implementation: http://pastebin.com/KdpS1Smg

Comment: I'm not very good in english and explanations at all, so i'll try to explain how it works. I have a wall builder application. A wall have two vertices. If wall building starts from existing another-wall vertex and ends with another-wall vertex, then app have to check is there have to be the floor. And i'm searching an optimal algorithm for that thing. Thanks

Comment: The BFS you describe will only find a *path* between the nodes; the OP needs a *cycle*.  -1 until you fix...

Comment: @user2890234 At a glance I see that you keep doing p.Clone and cl.Clone in the recursion. This means that you need to copy two arrays for every step and that makes your code O(N^2). You can avoid having to copy the array if you make sure you restore it before you return from the function. If you don't copy your code will also be O(N+M) so will likely run in time.